# Can I change the socket of a light fixture by simply cutting the old one off and re-wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

I currently have a wall light fixture that is only for small bulbs (I believe they are E14's):

[image: Wall light fixture]

Currently, Philips Hue does not manufacturer bulbs of this type. As a result, I am wondering how I can go about changing the socket size in order to get this light running Philips Hue bulbs. I'm specifically wondering if its as easy as cutting the old socket off and replacing with something like this:

[image: Lampholder white]

Are there any compatibility issues to consider? Given the wattage is different, I presume only the necessary amount of electricity will flow to the bulb? (i.e. there is no risk of the bulb receiving too much electricity).

Aside from ensuring the power is off, matching up the wires correctly and using marettes, any other recommendations or advice?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: If you put too large of a bulb in there, there could be heat issues (or even space issues). In general, don't try to upsize the wattage significantly.

Comment: Why do you think they are E14 bulbs, are you from Europe? Are you sure they are not US E12?

Comment: You say the wattage is different, but don't list the current bulb's wattage or the replacement bulb's wattage.  If you go with a lower wattage replacement incandescent, or any replacement CFL or LED bulb, you probably won't need to worry about the heat.  And to answer your question, yes, it really is that simple to wire in the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Hue system doesn't have any candelabra sized bulbs.  I don't see a Hue switch that would let you control the fixture as is.  All the Hue system bulbs look large.

There are adapters that will let you use standard bulbs in an e14 socket:

[image: E14 to E27 Socket Adapter]

I'm just not sure the bulb will fit in the fixture with the adapter - looks like it may be too small even without the adapter.  It might turn out to be easier to change the fixture.

(BTW, if you are in the US, you may want to check that it's really E14 and not E17 intermediate size socket.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see from your picture how those mount but you may want something more like this. 
[http://www.amazon.com/Leviton-3152-F-One-Piece-Incandescent-Lampholder/dp/B000HJBCFG/ref=sr_1_29?ie=UTF8&qid=1447723657&sr=8-29&keywords=Medium+base+screw+shell+sockets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HJBCFG)

And like the others said you can just swap bases as long as you don't overload the fixture.

Comment: There needs to be concern made for the size of bulb that would fit into the existing wall fixture once the fixture is re-assembled. From my look at the fixture picture in the question I rather doubt that standard sized bulbs will fit safely into the fixture once the socket if changed.